# On Webdriver, unable to upload the program due to following error, Please help

Tags: selenium, webdriver

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    at MyPackage.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You don't have the Google Guava library in your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/google/common/base/Function
>       at MyPackage.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:12)

This is probably because you added only `selenium-java-2.53.1.jar` into your build path. You also need to add `selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar`.